# Statistical difference of machine learning predictions

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation, method-comparison

I am applying a machine learning classification method to two difference scenarios for my boss (in this context, I am using a random forest). Due to the nature of the problem, there is high class imbalance; most points are expected to be labeled 0, while only about 5% are labeled 1.The classifer will generate predictions probabilities (between 0 and 1) for each point.

I have generated predictions for the two scenarios. It looks something like this [image: Scenario_examples]

In this plot each dot is a prediction, while the x and y axes are the scenarios.

**My Question**

I want to quantify the difference between the two methods in a fair way. However, due to the class imbalance using correlation (either spearman or pearson) is not fair: since most predictions are low confidence in both methods, it is correlation coefficients will always be high.

In previous analysis like this, I have picked a threshold (e.g. 50%) and quantified similarity above that threshold. Is there a more principled way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure, if the (linear) correlation is really a good metric for what you are trying to do. From looking at the plot, it seems that both methods/scenarios have very similar outcomes. The correlation is probably high. If you restrict the output values (of the forest/s), then the input space might be heavily distorted -- it's no longer a fair comparison of the outcomes, but rather placing a rather strong selection. How did you create the forest, did you use supervised learning? Then it might make more sense to compare the curves of efficiency/purity vs output value.

Comment: The methods do have similar outcome, but if you look at the plot closely, lower confidence predictions (i.e. lower left quadrant) are much more correlated than predictions that are higher confidence in one or the other. This was generated using a supervised learning approach.